# Filter for blanks on one column and fill for a value in another column

Tags: vba, excel

ive got this macro which filter out blanks and loops through the workbook

```
Sub Filter()


SearchCol = "Branch ID"
Dim ws As Object

For Each ws In Worksheets
Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
With ws.Range("A2")
    .AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
End With

Next ws

End Sub
```

Having done this i now want to search for another column, with this filter applied, and fill all cells in that column red with values of <4. so it needs to loop through the second searched for column called "amount" and fill cells where "amount" < 4 red and do this for all worksheets

Also i need showing how to mark questions correct on this, im probably being an idiot

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim SearchCol As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    SearchCol = "ID"

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        Set rng2 = ws.UsedRange.Find("Amount", , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            With ws
                .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="<>"
                .Range("A2").AutoFilter field:=rng2.Column, Criteria1:="<4"
                On Error Resume Next
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng2.Column).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range(.Cells(rng2.Row + 1, rng2.Column), .Cells(lastRow, rng2.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: i think i need to define a rng2 though dont i?

Comment: should field in the second autofilet be rng2?